# CoreData removes all objects after updating Model.xcdatamodeld

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, magicalrecord, core-data-migration

I am using MagicalRecord and Swift.

Here is my case:

- user has some history items in database. (user had some fitness sessions)
- Model.xcdatamodeld updated, like added new optimal attribute
- user starts the app and all history items removed.

Why? Any ways do handle that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are updating the xcdatamodeld file after running on your device and then running again, the chances are there is a conflict in xcdatamodeld files. You need to add a new version everytime you make changes to your data model. The current active xcdatamodel file is stored having `omo` extension. If this was the case the app would've crashed immediately and I see you updating your model maybe its something to do with MagicalRecord.